# Stack Overflow is not refreshing notifications

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow, notifications

I have found a minor bug on the Stack Overflow Website. The notifications are not getting refreshed automatically when we click on some particular notification and click the back button, The notification is still there and it does not get auto refresh.
Here are some screenshots.[image: This is when I have got some notification]

[image: When I view the notification and afterwards I click on back button of the browser]

[image: When I click on back button and go back on the page. The notification is still there]

When we click on the notification and view it.
When I click the back button on the browser, The notification is still there.
**In this way if the user wants to go back to the previous page then the user will always be confused if the notification is new or old.
My browser is Mozilla Firefox 70.0.1.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notifications return after hitting back button in browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215035/notifications-return-after-hitting-back-button-in-browser). The page is loaded from cache when you hit the back button.

Comment: @SebastianSimon So this bug is still not fixed even after 5 years. Because unlike Facebook it refreshes the notification even if we have clicked the back button.

Comment: @HarvindarSinghGarcha It's actually cached for speedy loading.